# ajax load function randomly loads and sometimes nothing just happens

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

hello all i am having a website and i am using ajax to load some page content after the document is fully ready.
but the issue is the code works fine in localhost and on some servers but not on my this server (currently shifted to new server) it just sometimes load and sometimes nothing happens also some times my custom error404 page loads .

i am using this code for the load

```
  $("#divtoload").load("pagename.php");
```

i have already checked that the page exists and is valid . the page has no issue/errors.

when i see the page by inspect element in chrome it shows me

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

please let me know where i am doing wrong .

Thanks in advance

the server error log says [Thu Jun 25 08:06:15 2015] [error] [client 112.196.134.168] (12)Cannot allocate memory: couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/username/public_html/page.php, referer: http://www.domain.com/page.php

Comment: Have you looked at the web server logs to see why the 500 is happening? It's server-side.

Comment: the server error log says [Thu Jun 25 08:06:15 2015] [error] [client 112.196.134.168] (12)Cannot allocate memory: couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/username/public_html/page.php, referer: http://www.domain.com/page.php